# How to add iPhone 5s simulator to Xcode 14.1?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Can not find iPhone 5s simulator in "Add Additional Simulators" section of Xcode 14.1 on Ventura 13.0. If I choose iPhone 5s in "Create a new simulator" window Xcode redirect me to Platforms, but there is no any platform for iPhone 5s simulator.
[image]

How can I add old simulators to new Xcode any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the following [guide](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-add-device-support-files-to-xcode-ce4ca5965092) which tells you how to download platforms that are not supported by Xcode. The oldest iOS platform available currently on Xcode is iOS 13.7 which is not supported by the iPhone 5s. You are being redirected to the platforms page because you don't currently have a valid iOS platform downloaded on Xcode. I hope the link I gave you helps! :)

Comment: That article does not in any way help with the question about adding a needed simulator.